# jQuery: onclick event not working when onkeyup working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JS / jQuery and use the following code try to implement:

1. click the button (`<a>`) to change the `<input>` value
2. input some numbers into the `<input>` directly

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoyo321/y3qxkuwx/)

So far everything works as intended but

**I cannot click the  button anymore when I input some number in the `<input>`**

Here is partial on **keyup** code

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#buy-num", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var t = $.trim( $buynum.val() );
    console.log(t);
    if( isNaN(Number(t)) || isEmpty(Number(t)) || isFloat(Number(t)) || Number(t) > 99 || Number(t) < 1 ){
        alert("Please input 1～99 ");
    }else{
        $buynum.attr("value", Number(t));
    }
    console.log("test");
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Replace `alert` with `console.log`. Since `alert` stops the code execution.

Comment: @Sushanth-- - I don't read whatever language that is, but I think the alert is to tell the user about a validation failure.

Comment: @nnnnnn My bad. You are correct.

Comment: @Sushanth , Thank you for your help. What should I do, If I want to keep the alert stay?

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right. It's just a validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to update the element with `$.val()` instead of `$.attr('value')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  var $add = $("#btn-add");
  var $reduce = $("#btn-reduce");
  var $buynum = $("#buy-num");

  var count = Number($buynum.val());

  $(document).on("click", "#btn-add", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var count = Number($buynum.val());
    var number = count + 1;

    if (number >= 199){
      $add.addClass("disabled");
      $reduce.removeClass("disabled");
      $buynum.val(199);
    } else {
      $add.removeClass("disabled");
      $buynum.val(number);
    }

    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // return false;

  });

  // reduce
  $(document).on("click", "#btn-reduce", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var count = Number($buynum.val());
    var number = count - 1;

    if (number <= 1){
      $buynum.val(1);
      $reduce.addClass("disabled");
      $add.removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
      $reduce.removeClass("disabled");
      $buynum.val(number);
    }

    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // return false;

  });

  // onkeyup
  $(document).on("keyup", "#buy-num", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var t = $.trim( $buynum.val() );
    console.log(t);
    // if ( isNaN(Number(t)) || t.length==0 || isFloat(Number(t)) || Number(t) > 199 || Number(t) < 1 ) {
    if ( isNaN(Number(t)) || isEmpty(Number(t)) || isFloat(Number(t)) || Number(t) > 199 || Number(t) < 1 ) {
      alert("请输入 1～199 之间的整数");
    } else {
      $buynum.val(Number(t));
    }
    console.log("test");
    return
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
});






function isEmpty(t){
  return "" == $.trim(t)
}

function isFloat(t){
  return Number(t) === t && t % 1 !== 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text buy-num" id="buy-num" value="1">
                   <a class="btn-reduce" id="btn-reduce" name="btn-reduce" href="#none">-</a>
                   <a class="btn-add" id="btn-add" name="add" href="#none">+</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly help. I have another two question: 1. What's the difference between `val()` and `attr()` ?  2. Must I add the `jquery.min.js` into  the html ?

Comment: @floox I think you mean what's the difference between `val()` and `attr('val')`? If so, `val()` sets/reads the current value of the element. `attr('val')` is the `value` _attribute_ of the element, which represents the initial value of the element, not the current value.

Comment: Thank your very much. It's a very clear explanation.